# TortoiseSVN Revision Log Dialog doesn't show up

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

When I click on "SVN Show log" from a context menu on any file, in any repository, the "show log" dialog never displays, but the tortoiseSVN icon DOES show up on the taskbar.

NOTES:
I have tried updating (to version 1.8), repairing (via tortoisesvn msi), and uninstalling/reinstalling (via tortoisesvn msi).

Version Information:
TortoiseSVN 1.8.2, Build 24708 - 64 Bit , 2013/08/27 19:20:39
Subversion 1.8.3, -release
apr 1.4.8
apr-util 1.5.2
serf 1.3.1
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
zlib 1.2.8

I don't think it matters, but this is on a windows 7 (professional) VM that I remote into.

Comment: I spent a week trying to figure this out and the second I posted the question I figured this out.

Settings>Saved Data
clicked "Clear" next to "Log messages (Show log dialog)"
and "Clear" next to Dialog sizes and positions.

If no one submits an answer before the 7 hour limit is up, I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings>Saved Data

clicked "Clear" next to "Log messages (Show log dialog)" and "Clear" next to Dialog sizes and positions.

Comment: For remote desktop users, you  may also need to right-click on the Log Messages Icon in system tray and choose Move.. Then use the arrow keys to move the dialog on screen.